# Is there difference between using a while loop and an if statement inside a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to use a recursive function to display the letters of the alphabet. If I use a while loop inside the function, the program goes on and on forever. But if I use an "if" statement inside that function instead of a while loop, the program works fine. To my intuition, I think that these are the same things. Can anyone explain me what's going on?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void alpha(char c);
main()
{
    alpha('A');
}
void alpha(char c)
{
    while(c<='Z')
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        alpha(c+1);
    }
}
//This program never stops.

#include<stdio.h>
void alpha(char c);
main()
{
    alpha('A');
}
void alpha(char c)
{
    if(c<='Z')
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        alpha(c+1);
    }
}
//This works fine.
```

For the first code, the output is ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZZZ.........(forever).For the second code, the output is ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.
I expect both of these outputs to be the same.

Comment: In the first snippet, the `c` variable is never incremented. `alpha` only calls itself with a new `c+1`, but its own `c` is left unchanged.

Comment: the data type of your main function is never declared. is it an int or double etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when the first version is called with `c='Z'` : ie: `alpha('Z')`?  In the following code:

```
while(c<='Z')        //Here you will loop forever because 'c' is not incremented
{
    printf("%c",c);  //This line will print 'Z'
    alpha(c+1);      //This line will call alpha('Z'+1) which will immediately
                     //return because the while loop in the next call frame 
                     //prevents further execution
}
```

This is why on your last recursive call, when `c='Z'`, your program will continue to print `'Z'` forever.

You probably want

```
while(c<='Z')
{
    printf("%c",c);
    ++c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The body of an `if` block will only run once provided the condition is met, whereas the body of a `while` will run multiple times as long at the condition is true.  In this case:

```
while(c<='Z')
{
    printf("%c",c);
    alpha(c+1);
}
```

You're in a loop checking the value of `c`.  Since `c` never changes, the loop never ends.

Your second program is the proper way to handle a recursive function.  The function won't get called recursively unless some condition is met, and if so it makes the recursive call then returns when the recursive call is done.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call the recursive function when you called the while loop, and they will function exactly as the if-block code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void alpha(char c);
main()
{
    alpha('A');
}
void alpha(char c)
{
    while(c<='Z')
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        c= c+1;
    }
}
```

Now as to why your code is reaming in infinite loop is because when `while(c<='Z')`becomes false after recursive calls it will go back to previous call (i.e when `c=='Z'`) and as `c` never increments it remains in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a space after %c it's a buffer. Any time you use a loop you need an incrementor. An if statement will run once and close the program out, the while loop will keep it running infinitely unless the exit condition is met.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void alpha(char c);
int main()
{
    alpha('A');
}
void alpha(char c)
{
    while (c != toupper('Z'))
    {
        printf("%c ", c);
        c++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```